# How to remove nulls in my list variable?

Tags: scala, list, null

I have the following list input:

```
List(List(first, sec, null, null), List(third, null, null))
```

I need to remove `null`<sub><sup>s</sup></sub> from my list, in order to get:

```
List(List(first, sec), List(third))
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have *nested List* as

```
val data = List(List("first", "sec", null, null), List("third", null, null))
```

Then use `map` and `filterNot` as

```
data.map(_.filterNot(_ == null))
//res0: List[List[String]] = List(List(first, sec), List(third))
```

Or you can use `map` and `filter` as

```
data.map(_.filter(_ != null))
//res0: List[List[String]] = List(List(first, sec), List(third))
```

I hope the answer is helpful

Answer (score 6):

Given this list:

```
val list = List(List("first", "sec", null, null), List("third", null, null))
```

And the fact that `Option(null)` gives `None`, then:

```
list.map(_.flatMap(Option(_)))
```

produces:

```
List(List("first", "sec"), List("third"))
```